# why the swap part is executing again after the function hit return statement

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, selection-sort

the code is working fine till end and i am getting a sorted array, but after sorting it is again executing swap part code , but the issue is getting solved by adding else to the swap method.

```
    if(i==0){
        return;
    }
    if(j<=i){
        if(arr[j]>arr[max]){
            max=j;             //finding the max element in array
        }
        SS(arr,i,j+1,max);
    }
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[max];       //swapping the max element.
    arr[max] = temp;
    SS(arr, i - 1, 0, 0);
}
```

}

This is working:

```
    if(i==0){
        return;
    }
    if(j<=i){
        if(arr[j]>arr[max]){
            max=j;
        }
        SS(arr,i,j+1,max);
    }
    else{
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[max];
    arr[max] = temp;
    SS(arr, i - 1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

}

what are the differences ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, without going deep into the algorithm, you have additional `i++;` in the second `if` branch in the second example.

Moreover in the first example the swap will happen even if the `j<=i` condition is met because you did not add `return` - it will not happen in the second example.